# Visual Studio change plattform settings back from Any CPU to x86

Tags: visual-studio

In a solution which contains some c# projects, we build all projects for "Any CPU" platform. 
We are 3 developers which work on this solution and use svn as source control. We do not add/commit the .suo file to the source control.

From time to time, visual studio resets the platform from "Any CPU" to x86. 
The reset happens on different computers from different users sporadically.

[image: Changed byck automatically by Visual Studio]

I've found similar questions here on stackoverflow, but no reason for such a behavior was presented, only the advice to reset this setting and to check the .suo file.

What could be the reason that this platform is reset/changed from time to time?

Comment: I got a bloody nose yesterday because of this. I removed `*.suo` files from version control as they contain user specific data. That changed the platform setting from x86 to Any_CPU for anyone checking out a fresh copy. It would be really good if there was another solution to safely store the platform other then versioning user settings that change all the time. I use VS2010.